# Material CheckBox with UNIQUE selection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, radio-button

I'm struggling from 2 days on this problem in my angular2+bootstrap+material project.

I need to change the material design checkbox:

- *When i check a checkbox from my table, that check have to be the only one*

I know that i can use a material radio button, but in that case i have another problem : i can't uncheck the radio button.

So i need to enable unique check and also check/uncheck functions.

[image]

I've tried the following

- Interact with dom with document.getElement.blablabla
- Used dom interpolation of angular 2
- Javascript function
- Jquery function

Here's the **code** of html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <label>Ordini cliente</label>
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

        <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
              The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

        <!-- Select Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Select">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"><mat-checkbox color="primary"></mat-checkbox></mat-cell>
        </ng-container>


        //OTHER COLUMNS ...

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>


</div>
```

My idea was to bind the element to a click event like this

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"><mat-checkbox (click)="foo()" color="primary"></mat-checkbox></mat-cell>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set a property to keep track of which one is checked. And then set [checked] for only the one which is chosen. Here, for example, I keep the track with ngFor index:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3];  let i = index">
  <mat-checkbox [checked]="selected === i" (change)="selected = i">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrnk7t?file=src/app/checkbox-overview-example.html)

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot. 
ps: i've decided to use a normal html 5 table and then materializa the style , because in material table we don't have explicit ngFor sintax to bend at our logic.

Comment: how i use binding for same ngmodel with multiple options

Comment: This will throw `Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.`

Comment: @B45i, could you provide a demo? It is related to your code and that error can be trown for many reasons

Comment: Simple and straightforward, worked like a charm! thanks a lot.